# Exchange activesync manage devices external api

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, activesync

I would like to manage Exchange ActiveSync devices (add device, remove, list devices, add policies to devices etc) via external rest api.
This means that I would like to execute cmdlets commands for exchange (such as described here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641223(v=exchg.160).aspx) via external api (e.g SOAP, REST) and not internally from the machine.

Is this possible, or do I have to implement an API on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exchange Management Shell cmldets can be executed via Remote Powershell from Exchange 2010 up so you can put your REST code on any WebServer that itself can establish a Remote Powershell connection back to the Target Exchange Server. Using that method avoids needing to make any changes to the Exchange Server.

Comment: Will the cmdlets commands (like remove devices per mailbox) only affect the ActiveSync connections or all exchange account will be disabled?

Comment: Your question isn't clear because you haven't provided enough information on which particular cmdlet and action, but this is something you should test yourself first then ask a question based on your observations, understanding and problems. Cmdlets as a general rule only affect the configuration of the particular mailbox you modifying.

Comment: thanks. basically I want to quarantine all devices per mailbox using 
Set-ActiveSyncDeviceAccessRule 'SomeDeviceID' -AccessLevel Quarantine

Comment: Sure that should work fine http://exchangeserverpro.com/preventing-new-activesync-device-types-from-connecting-to-exchange-server-2010/ and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/65805ccc-9fee-4026-a7af-6e1dc8c3cbc8/enable-quarantine-what-about-existing-devices?forum=exchangesvrmobility . I would suggest you test it in Powershell first get it working then create your manage code.